# Python API looping to get DateTime Indexed Dataframe beyond max sample size

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to improve my Python script to pull more data samples into a single dataframe than the host allows in one "call". This is time-based data set I am pulling from a campus BMS (Building Management System [JCI Metasys]) that limits my samples to 10,000. Not all samples are taken in uniform intervals so when using `pd.dropnan` I may end up with far less than this amount of samples to each column of data.

I am looking to see if there is a better way to pull large amounts of data with an API. Since I am dropping rows with any nan values, I am thinking that collecting subsequent columns and dropping a row where a nan already exist in previous rows could be skipped to speed-up the process. I am very "green" and general direction would be helpful.

I use a looping function (all_data) to call get multiple iterations from get_data. Any assistance would be appreciated. Here is the code that I am using and can be finnicky:

```
def Metasys():
    tokenParams = {'token': '', 'expire': ''}
    pointsList = {'ref': '', 'id': ''}
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.metasysapi.v4+json'
    }
    url = 'https://*IP ADDRESS*/api/v4/login'
    body = '{"username": "USER", "password": "PASSWORD"}'
    r = requests.post(url,
                    data=body,
                    headers=headers,
                    verify=False,
                    timeout=5)
    r_dict = r.json()
    tokenParams['token'] = r_dict['accessToken']
    token = r_dict['accessToken']
    tokenParams['expire'] = r_dict['expires']
    return token


def get_data(fqr_list, start, end, samples, dropnan):
    token = Metasys()
    df_data = pd.DataFrame()
    start = start.astimezone(pytz.utc)  # Convert to UTC
    end = end.astimezone(pytz.utc)  # Convert to UTC
    end = end.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    start = start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    print(start)
    for i in range(len(fqr_list)):
        fqr=str(fqr_list[i])
        print(fqr)
        fqr_url = 'https://*IP ADDRESS/api/v4/objectIdentifiers?fqr=' + fqr

        auth_string = 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': auth_string}
        r = requests.get(fqr_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        r_dict = r.json()
        objID = str(r_dict)

        trend_url='https://*IP ADDRESS*/api/v4/objects/'+objID+'/trendedAttributes/presentValue/samples?startTime='+start+'&endTime='+end+'&page=1&pageSize='+samples+'&sort=timestamp'
        Bearer='Bearer '+token

        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': Bearer
        }

        auth_string = 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': auth_string}

        r = requests.get(trend_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = r.json()
        data_raw = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['items'])
        df_temp = data_raw[['timestamp', 'value.value']]
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'value.value':fqr,'timestamp':'Time'})
        df_temp['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['Time'])
        df_temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_temp.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
        df_data=pd.concat([df_data, df_temp], axis=1)
    if dropnan == 1:
            df_data.dropna(inplace = True)
    df_data.index=pd.to_datetime(df_data.index, format='%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S-f')
    df=df_data
    #df=df.drop_duplicates()
    col_list = ["BCONTROLS1:"]
    for i in range(len(col_list)):
        df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(col_list[i], "", regex=True)
    return df



def all_data(fqr_list, start, end, samples, dropnan):
    print(f"Start =>> {start}")
    print(f" End =>> {end}")
    print(f" Samples =>> {samples}")
    print(f" dropnan =>> {dropnan}")
    df = get_data(fqr_list, start, end, samples, dropnan); start = df.index[-1]
    df_next = df
    while len(df_next) > 1:
        print(start)
        df_next = get_data(fqr_list, start, end, samples, dropnan); start = df_next.index[-1]
        df = pd.concat([df, df_next])
        df = df.drop_duplicates()
    df = df.tz_convert('US/Central')  # Convert Back to Central
    df = df.tz_localize(None)  # Make date naive
    hdr = list(df.columns)
    idx = list(df.index)
    out = {'data': df, 'idx': idx, 'hdr': hdr}
    return out
```

I am looking to see if there is a better way to pull large amounts of data with an API. Since I am dropping rows with any nan values, I am thinking that collecting subsequent columns and dropping a row where a nan already exist in previous rows could be skipped to speed-up the process. I am very "green" and general direction would be helpful.

Comment: when i see "loop" and "dataframe" in the same sentence i know there is a red flag.

Comment: for loops and dataframes: https://youtu.be/0EkFJNTOs7E

Comment: I see that there are a few comments saying dataframes and loops do not go well together and that is all well and good. But I was hoping for some way of using time indexed data with multiple columns. The way I see it, I am not really looping over the dataframe so much as pulling the data and putting it into a dataframe.

Comment: if the code is doing this inside a for loop, then it is "looping" over the dataframe and will lose efficiency... However, the loss may be small for a small dataset.

Comment: @Bobert Please explain what specific promblem/question you need help with. "Any assistance" is too broad to be useful. (Still, you got good advice against concatenating dataframes inside a loop!)

Comment: @MB-F Ya, critiques like above do assist me in knowing what I am doing wrong but I am unsure as to how best to make this more effective/efficient. In light of previous comments, I am looking to see if there is a better way to pull large amounts of data with an API without looping if possible. I was surprised to not find an existing post addressing this type of situation. Since I am dropping rows with any nan values, I am thinking that collecting subsequent columns and dropping a row where a nan already exist can be skipped. I am very "green" and general direction would be helpful.